# combinations word problems math

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, word-problem

There are two different problems I am stuck on.

1. In how many ways can we divide ten candies of the same kind among four children?

I haven't found a way to solve this one

2.In how many ways can we partition a group of 8 boys and 4 girls into two teams A and B having four boys and two girls each?

i thought maybe of going at it in thinking of only one group, (the second will also have to contain 4 boys and 2 girls if one does) `8 choose 4 has 70 options ----4 choose 2 has 6 options

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Note of Caution ... this will double count the teams! So we need to ...

Comment: For the first, see [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) or search the site for that

Comment: donald, are you saying 76 is double the answer? Could you elaborate.

Comment: You have to multiply, not add, so your technique will come up with $420$ possible ways of dividing the kids into teams.  This is double the correct answer because, since the teams are indistinguishable, the division that assigns the first $4$ boys and the first $2$ girls to the team you're tracking is the same as the division that assigns the last $4$ boys and the last $2$ girls to that team.

Comment: wow thanks Robert that helps a lot! for the second i got 36 but i don't think its the correct answer.

Comment: For question 2, there are $\binom{8}{4}=70$ possible ways to choose 4 boys out of the 8. There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose 2 girls out of the 4. Now to pick your team, you first select one of 4 boys out the 70 possible choices of boys then select the 2 girls out the 6 choices to get $70*6=420$ possible choice. By doing that, you have partitioned the children into two teams. So the partitioning of children really only depends on the first 4 boys and first 2 girls that you choose to form one of the two team.  The order of the choice doesn't matter so So you get $\frac{420}{2}=210$.

Comment: For the first question, you are partitioning ten candies into four groups.  You can put the candies side by side and then put three bar between the sweets to separate them.  There are nine places to put the bars. So the sol should be $\binom{9}{3}=84$.